# sleep command in threaded application

Tags: c++, windows, thread-sleep

The Sleep(ms) command in windows is causing threads to release their timeslices. Is there an equivalent Sleep(ms) command that halts the thread but does not release the timeslice?

Comment: Why would you want to busy-wait?

Comment: @Erik, the thread in question is controlling a piece of hardware. If it tries to send two successive commands without waiting at least 500 ms in between commands, the command does not register.

Comment: @rossb83: And why does that require you to avoid `Sleep`?

Comment: @Erik because when Sleep is finished it takes a long time for the thread to get its time slices back. Other threads are doing very intensive computations.

Comment: Add this information about your problem in the original post, not only in the comments.

Comment: @rossb83: Give this thread the highest priority you can, and the others a lower. Then use Sleep.

Comment: 500 milliseconds is very well within Sleep's resolution and accuracy. Had you said 500 microseconds... but for milliseconds, just go with Sleep. Even more so as you said "at least", which suggests that you don't really need 500.000000, but 501 or 510 will be acceptable too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want your thread to sleep (aka suspend), you want to stall it. Do that with a simple loop:

```
#include <time.h>

void stall(unsigned ms){
    clock_t goal = clock()+ms;
    while(goal>clock());
}
// or maybe higher resolution with some performance profiling functions...
```

Answer (score 1):

Strange.

A way to do that is to make your thread execute a loop till the end of the periode needed.

A better solution may be to give the thread handling the device a high priority. But anyway, Windows is not very suitable for real-time systems...